# Спавн экземпляра класса в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, объекты

я не так давно в программировании, так что вопрос тоже не самый адекватный.
я хочу создать несколько npc в своей игре (2D), так что решил создать класс для этого.

Класс имеет GameObject - префаб, строку - имя и два массива строк - фразы и названия анимаций (кстати если у кого то есть другой здоровый способ использовать анимации через код, нежели не с помощью имен, прошу помогите!). я решил проверить спавн, создал экземпляр, написал в старте Instantiate, и тут же был уведомлен, что метод работает только для типа Object, ну и GameObject.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как  организовать класс или не класс, хотя бы какую то структурированную систему хранения npc, потому что для каждой локации предусмотрены свои фразы и анимации, хотелось бы это как-то организовать. Если есть что-то лучше зранения отдельно каждого префаба с кучей if в общем скрипте, для проверки сцены (в моей игре сцена это просто задний фон из соседнего скрипта, а не сцена unity).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPCCreator : MonoBehaviour
{

[System.Serializable]
public  class Person
{   
    public string name;
    public GameObject body;
    public string[] phrases;
    public string[] animations;
}
public Person Green = new Person();

public static NPCCreator instance;
void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}
void Start()
{
   Instantiate(Green, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала создайте общий класс Npc  в котором будут поля которые могут быть у каждого npc, дальше создайте, например, класс  NpcGreen, который унаследуйте от класса npc, прописав в нем индивидуальный функционал. В инспекторе повесьте соответствующие скрипты на npc и заполните поля. В классе  NPCCreator который будет проинициализирован в начале игры, можете Instantiate-вать ваших npc  с уже существующими полями и функционалом. Примерно как может выглядеть код.

```
/// Класс NPC

public class Npc : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected string name; //можно и public если очень надо
    protected string[] phrases;
    protected string[] animations;

    //общий функционал npc
    protected void Awake()
    {
        // общий функционал npc
    }
    protected void Start()
    {
        // общий функционал npc
    }
    // и тд
}

/// Класс NpcGreen
public class NpcGreen : Npc
{
    
    //функционал npc Green
    private new void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        // доп функционал npc Green
    }
    
    private new void Update()
    {
        base.Update();
        // доп функционал npc Green
    }
    // и тд
}


/// Класс NPC Creator
public class NPCCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject npcGreen;

    private void Awake()
    {
        
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        Instantiate(npcGreen, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    // и тд
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за полезную инфу! постараюсь это использовать в полной мере.